# Custom circle respect to content length in react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios

I want to draw custom circle respect to inside content length. I tried using `height:100`, `width:100`, `borderRadius:50` but it is static when content increases it will looks inconvenient. I googled but it gives me same solution.

**Required output** https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvRu9.png

**My output** https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VcOv.png

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that with the help of `minWidth` and a little `padding`

Try this with the dynamic content

```
<View style={{height: 100, minWidth: 100, paddingLeft: 10, paddingRight: 10, borderRadius: 50, backgroundColor: 'red', alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}} >
    <Text>// Dynamic Text</Text>
</View>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not give **static width and height**.

Pass a prop called onLayoutChange to your View, the callback will give you the height and width of your view before it changes.

You can then use either width or height to calculate the border radius, according to your requirement.

> But my suggestion would be to use a static height and not to pass
>   width, and give a border radius half of that of the height, this will
>   help you achieve your required goal

Answer (score 0):

```
Use This code    
<ul class="size-List">
         <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">S</a></li>
         <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">M</a></li>
         <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">L</a></li>
         <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">XL</a></li>
         <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">XXL</a></li>
       </ul>
    <style>
    .size-List{
        list-style:none;
    }
    .size-List li{
        display:inline-block;
    }
    .size-List li a{
        border:1px solid gray;
        width:45px;
        height:45px;
        color:gray;
        line-height:45px;
        text-align:center;
        display:block;
        border-radius:100%;
        text-decoration:none;
        font-size:16px;
    }
    </style>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer @renuka but as per I indicate in my question I want dynamic circle style which will increase/decrease respect to content length and `borderRadius` can't work with `%` in react-native.